# LINQ Data Context Not Showing Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datacontext

For some reason my DataContext is not showing all the normal methods like SubmitChanges() etc in the intellisense.

It also won't compile if I type in db.SubmitChanges();

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Normally I don't have this issue, I have several other projects that work fine...

Image of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linq to sql dbml file might be corrupt or someone might have changed/deleted the code behind file. Try creating a new linq to sql dbml with a new context NeebitDBContext2. See if you get submitchanges.

Comment: Started over with a new project and copied all my stuff into it.  Works now.  Just making a new dbml file didn't work.  But something was definitely corrupt / broken / set wrong.